# Windows 8 couldn't be activated: The URL is invalid

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-activation

Error code: 0x80072EE5

Error description: The URL is invalid

Has anyone seen this before? Is it possible to activate by phone in windows 8?

I got another product key from MSDN and ran slui 3 to change it, same issue. Its a desktop so if its a dns problem it will be a pain to move, other pcs on the same network activated fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ran slui 4, that brings up phone activation, worked perfectly.